# Annotate RoughViz chart using Rough-Notation library

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I have a simple bar chart built with RoughViz.js. The key takeaway that I'd like to highlight in the chart is the difference in height between the first bar and the third bar. To do this I'd like to use the bracket annotation from Rough Notation and set the bracket to start at a y-coordiate equal to the height of the first bar and end at a y-coordinate equal to the height of the last bar. What is the best way to accomplish this?

EDIT...
this picture illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish. The large bracket is the one that the rough-notation library is drawing in my code. Note that it wraps the entire chart. I want it to instead draw the bracket like the small dark blue one that I've mocked up. The dashed lines are also just mock up so as to better convey the desired positioning.
[image]

The external libraries are:
https://github.com/jwilber/roughViz and
https://github.com/rough-stuff/rough-notation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rough-viz@1.0.6"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/rough-notation?module"></script>

    <style>
      body {}

      ;

      .item1 {
        grid-area: chart;
      }

      .item2 {
        grid-area: annotation;
      }

      .grid-container {
        margin-top: 3rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
          'chart annotation';
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 8fr, 3fr;

      }

      #typedtext {
        font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', cursive;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 10px 50px;
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: blue;
        padding-left: 3rem;
        padding-top: 30%;
        height: 100%;

      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="annotate-button">Click me</button>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">
        <div id="viz0"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item2">
        <div id="typedtext"></div>
      </div>

    </div>





  </body>

</html>
<script>
  // create Bar chart from csv file, using default options
  new roughViz.Bar({
    element: '#viz0', // container selection
    data: {
      labels: ['First thing', 'Second thing', 'Third thing'],
      values: [100, 50, 25]
    },
    width: window.innerWidth * .7,
    height: window.innerHeight * .7
  });

</script>

<script type="module">
  import { annotate } from 'https://unpkg.com/rough-notation?module';
    const e = document.querySelector('#viz0');
const annotation = annotate(e, { type: 'bracket', color: 'blue', padding: [2, 10], strokeWidth: 3 });
document.getElementById("annotate-button").addEventListener('click', function(){
    annotation.show();
})

</script>

<script>
  //https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/

  // set up text to print, each item in array is new line
  var aText = new Array(
    "This is a comment"
  );
  var iSpeed = 10; // time delay of print out
  var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
  var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
  var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

  var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
  var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
  var iRow; // initialise current row

  function typewriter() {
    sContents = ' ';
    iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex - iScrollAt);
    var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

    while (iRow < iIndex) {
      sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
    }
    destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) + "_";
    if (iTextPos++ == iArrLength) {
      iTextPos = 0;
      iIndex++;
      if (iIndex != aText.length) {
        iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
        setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
      }
    } else {
      setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("annotate-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    typewriter();
  })

</script>
```

You can also click here for a JsFiddle with the same code. The chart renders a little better on JsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/hughesdan/bmyda74e/1/

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. You will find additional/changed code documented properly. It would be better to test the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/fo16n8tu/.

Rough annotation plugin needs HTML/SVG element to select and annotate. Therefore, I add a dummy `<rect>` element and use it for annotation. Let me know if this approach could work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rough-viz@1.0.6"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/rough-notation?module"></script>

    <style>
      body {}


      .item1 {
        grid-area: chart;
      }

      .item2 {
        grid-area: annotation;
      }

      .grid-container {
        margin-top: 3rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
          'chart annotation';
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 8fr, 3fr;

      }

      #typedtext {
        font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', cursive;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 10px 50px;
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: blue;
        padding-left: 3rem;
        padding-top: 30%;
        height: 100%;

      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="annotate-button">Click me</button>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">
        <div id="viz0"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item2">
        <div id="typedtext"></div>
      </div>

    </div>





  </body>

</html>
<script>
  // create Bar chart from csv file, using default options
  const viz = new roughViz.Bar({
    element: '#viz0', // container selection
    data: {
      labels: ['First thing', 'Second thing', 'Third thing'],
      values: [100, 50, 25]
    },
    width: window.innerWidth * .7,
    height: window.innerHeight * .7
  });

</script>

<script type="module">
  import { annotate } from 'https://unpkg.com/rough-notation?module';
    const e = document.querySelector('#viz0');
   
   /* START additional code */ 
    // Select <g id="#viz0_svg"> element
    const svgGroupWrapper = e.querySelector('[id="#viz0_svg"]');
    // Get each bar <g> element
        const bars = svgGroupWrapper.getElementsByClassName('viz0');
    // Height difference between the first (bars[0]) and the third bar (bars[2])
    const diffHeight = bars[0].getBoundingClientRect().height - bars[2].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    // Get the position annotation element by horizontal x-axis
    const offsetX = svgGroupWrapper.getElementsByClassName('rough-xAxisviz0')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    // Width of annotation element (also used in annotation options!!!)
    const annotationPadding = [0, 6];
    // Create dummy <rect> element to annotate on it. Annotation needs an HTML element to work
    
    const elementToAnnotate = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','rect');
    // Set "x" attribute to offsetX - annotationPadding[1] - 1 to shift <rect> to very right, but with place for annotaion and width of rect (=1)
    elementToAnnotate.setAttribute('x', offsetX - annotationPadding[1] - 1);
    // Just positioning "y" to 0 so that the element start from top of the SVG
    elementToAnnotate.setAttribute('y', '0');
    // Set "width" to 1 to be identifable in SVG for annotation plugin
    elementToAnnotate.setAttribute('width', '1');
    // Set "height" to the height difference value between first and third bars
    elementToAnnotate.setAttribute('height', diffHeight);
    // Set "fill" to transparent so that the <rect> element is not visible for users
    elementToAnnotate.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
    // Add the element in wrapper <g> element
    svgGroupWrapper.appendChild(elementToAnnotate);
    /* END additional code */
    
// CHANGED CODE: Annotate dummy <rect> element for desired effects
const annotation = annotate(elementToAnnotate, { type: 'bracket', color: 'blue', padding: annotationPadding, strokeWidth: 3 });

document.getElementById("annotate-button").addEventListener('click', function(){
    annotation.show();
})

</script>

<script>
  //https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/

  // set up text to print, each item in array is new line
  var aText = new Array(
    "This is a comment"
  );
  var iSpeed = 10; // time delay of print out
  var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
  var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
  var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

  var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
  var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
  var iRow; // initialise current row

  function typewriter() {
    sContents = ' ';
    iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex - iScrollAt);
    var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

    while (iRow < iIndex) {
      sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
    }
    destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) + "_";
    if (iTextPos++ == iArrLength) {
      iTextPos = 0;
      iIndex++;
      if (iIndex != aText.length) {
        iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
        setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
      }
    } else {
      setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("annotate-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    typewriter();
  })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like in the following example:

```js
const lbls = ['First thing', 'Second thing', 'Third thing'];
const destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");
const empty = (data) => {           
    switch (true) {
      case (data == null || data == 'undefined' || data == false || data == ''):
        return true;
      case (Array.isArray(data)):
        return data.length == 0;
      case (typeof data == 'object'):
        return (Object.keys(data).length == 0 && data.constructor == Object);
      case (typeof data == 'string'):
        return data.length == 0;
      case (typeof data == 'number' && !isNaN(data)):
        return data == 0;
      default:
        return false;
    }
}
const typewriter = () => { 

    settings.sContents = ' ';
    settings.iRow = Math.max(0, settings.iIndex - settings.iScrollAt);
    while (settings.iRow < settings.iIndex) {
      settings.sContents += settings.aText[settings.iRow++] + '<br />';
    }
    if(!empty(settings.aText[settings.iIndex])) {
        destination.textContent = settings.sContents + settings.aText[settings.iIndex].substring(0, settings.iTextPos) + "_";
    }
    
    if (settings.iTextPos++ == settings.iArrLength) {
      settings.iTextPos = 0;
      settings.iIndex++;
      if (!empty(settings.aText[settings.iIndex]) && settings.iIndex != settings.aText.length) {
        settings.iArrLength = settings.aText[settings.iIndex].length;
        setTimeout(typewriter(), 500);
      }
    } else {
      setTimeout(typewriter(), settings.iSpeed);
    }
}
new roughViz.Bar({
  element: '#viz0', // container selection
  data: {
    labels: lbls,
    values: [100, 50, 25]
  },
  width: window.innerWidth * 0.7,
  height: window.innerHeight * 0.7
});


var settings = {};
settings.diff = [];
lbls.forEach((label) => {
  let g = document.querySelector('g[attrX=\"' + label + '\"]');
  g.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let b = parseInt(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('attrY'));
    if (e.target.getAttribute('fill') == '#ff0000') {
      e.target.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
      let index = settings.diff.indexOf(b);
      settings.diff = settings.diff.filter((x, i) => i !== index);
    } else {
      e.target.setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');
      settings.diff.push(b);
    }
});
});
document.getElementById("annotate-button").addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  if (settings.diff.length == 2) {
    settings.aText = [(settings.diff[0] - settings.diff[1]).toString()];    
  } else {
    settings.aText = ['Select a pair first!'];
  }
  settings.iSpeed = 10; // time delay of print out
  settings.iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision

  settings.iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

  settings.iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
  settings.sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
  settings.iRow = 0; // initialise current row
  settings.iArrLength = settings.aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
  typewriter();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rough-viz@1.0.6"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/rough-notation?module"></script>
    <script type="module">
      import { annotate } from 'https://unpkg.com/rough-notation?module';
    const ee = document.querySelector('#viz0');
const annotation = annotate(ee, { type: 'bracket', color: 'blue', padding: [2, 10], strokeWidth: 3 });
document.getElementById("annotate-button").addEventListener('click', function(){
    annotation.show();
})

</script>
    <style>
      body {}

      ;

      .item1 {
        grid-area: chart;
      }

      .item2 {
        grid-area: annotation;
      }

      .grid-container {
        margin-top: 3rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
          'chart annotation';
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 8fr, 3fr;

      }

      #typedtext {
        font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', cursive;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 10px 50px;
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: blue;
        padding-left: 3rem;
        padding-top: 30%;
        height: 100%;

      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="annotate-button">Click me</button>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">
        <div id="viz0"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item2">
        <div id="typedtext"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

OR use this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk3caem9/6/)

Comment: Thank you. I've added an illustration to hopefully clarify the question. What I'm trying to do is draw the bracket in a different position. Hopefully this is clear now. Also I've just renewed the bounty as I noticed it expired.